# Can a plone.behavior be enabled for just some objects of a type?

Tags: plone, dexterity

I would like to set a marker interface to some objects that should have additional fields. If I remove this marker interface again the fields should be removed too.

Now I'm trying to understand plone.behavior. But I'm not sure if a behavior must be enabled for all objects of a type or is it possible to enable it for only a subset of objects of that type?

Comment: What distinguishes the subset? Is it based on a particular value in a certain field? Is membership in the subset set once at create time or is it dynamic? Why can't you have two types, one with the behavior and one without?

Comment: The subset of objects is distinguished by providing a marker interface or not. The membership in the subset is dynamic. To have to two types is maybe a "plan B".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [collective.instancebehavior](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.instancebehavior), an add-on aimed to do exactly what you want: to enable behaviors per content type instance.

Comment: This looks great. Thank you. I have already thought about writing my own implemtation of `IBehaviorAssignable`.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I don't think there is a solution out of the box.
The simplest thing you can do is working on the form fields by overriding the updateFields method in the form.
This is untested demo code:

```
def updateFields(self):
    if not IMyInterface.providedBy(self.context):
        self.fields = (
            self.fields.omit('IMyBehaviour.my_field')
        )
```

As a reference have a look to:

- https://github.com/plone/plone.app.users/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=def+updateFields

Comment: Thx, alepisa - this works. But it is not so elegant because my EditForm has to know the marker interface and the behavior fields. If you have any other (non simple) ideas I would be happy to hear about them.

Comment: I am not aware of anything simplier at the moment, but inside the updateFields you can call an adapter or a view (that are marker interface aware) and use the to fiddle the fields. I don't think this is really practical in the end.